# Unexpected value while creating BoxMetadata

Tags: ios, box

My iOS app is accessing to BOX API via BOXContentSDK. Suddenly, I'm receiving unexpected types(int) for 'version' and 'typeversion' while creating BOXMetadata which is causing crash because of assertion below at NSJSONSerialization+BOXAdditions.m

```
+ (id)box_ensureObjectForKey:(NSString *)key inDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary hasExpectedType:(Class)cls nullAllowed:(BOOL)nullAllowed
{
    id object = [dictionary objectForKey:key];
    id extractedObject = object;
    if ([object isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    {
        if (nullAllowed)
        {
            extractedObject = [NSNull null];
        }
        else
        {
            BOXAssertFail(@"Unexpected JSON null when extracting key %@ from dictionary %@", key, dictionary);
            extractedObject = nil;
        }
    }
    else if (object == nil)
    {
        extractedObject = nil;
    }
    else if (![object isKindOfClass:cls])
    {
        BOXAssertFail(@"Unexpected type when extracting key %@ from dictionary %@\nExpected type %@ but instead got %@", key, dictionary, NSStringFromClass(cls), NSStringFromClass([object class]));
        extractedObject = nil;
    }
    return extractedObject;
}
```

Here is the exception that I got from assertion above;

```
Expected type NSString but instead got __NSCFNumber'
```

The sample response JSON in below;

```
{"documenttype":"Inspections","categories":"Inspections","reportdocumenttype":"","documentTag":"SR000070022803","csa.internal.only":"false","$type":"properties","$parent":"file_42748776033","$id":"314f1a71-7ecf-4e6f-a765-8a6eaefed6d3","$version":0,"$typeVersion":0,"$template":"properties","$scope":"global"}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out, Alp. Our Metadata SDK code got out-of-sync with the fact that values are no longer required to be strings (can have integer and float values in metadata). That is the main change you will see in https://github.com/box/box-ios-sdk/pull/134, which contains the fix for this issue.

Please let us know if you run into further issues.

Good luck,
Tom